# 'Unauthorized' error creating app service plan

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code

Don't know where exactly it is failing. I'm using VS Code to create the following script and running from there only:

```
$ResourceGroupName="powershell-grp"
$Location="North Europe"
$AppServicePlanName="PowershellAppService1975"
$WebAppName="PowershellWebApp1975"

Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Enterprise" | Select-AzSubscription
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location 
New-AzAppServicePlan -Name $AppServicePlanName -Location $Location -Tier "B1" -NumberofWorkers 1 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName -Location $Location -AppServicePlan $AppServicePlanName
```

And in the powershell console, i get this error:
New-AzAppServicePlan: C:\Temp\AzureCmds\Azure Powershell-WebApp\Script1.ps1:9:1
Line |
9 |  New-AzAppServicePlan -Name $AppServicePlanName -Location $Location -T …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

New-AzWebApp: C:\Temp\AzureCmds\Azure Powershell-WebApp\Script1.ps1:10:1
Line |
10 |  New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName  …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Answer (score 0):

Used -debug cmdlet option that gave the exact info on the issue.
The resource group location supported 0 instances for the chosen app service plan. Therefore, deployed app service plan and the web app to an altogether different location